# Getting full dependencies graphs of .NET solutions

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Given a solution (or a project), how could you get a full dependency graph ? By dependency graph I mean all required DLL and especially NuGets packages, with their own dependencies (recursively).

A dependency graph can be used for inventory purpose, but especially to spot conflict in package version.

The question concerns .NET Framework and .NET Core.

**EDIT :** to troubleshoot a solution this Friday I made a quick & dirty script using Ruby to extract useful data from the package folders (.NET Framework) : https://gist.github.com/samonzeweb/1ed1498e901ce79d054e0116ec70c113 . It helped me, and could help somebody else, but it's not a proper nor standard way to do it ;)

Comment: This might be helpful: [Analyzing .NET Core project dependencies: Finding transitive dependencies](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/analyze-dotnet-project-dependencies-part-2/).

Comment: Tanks for the link.
This Friday I also found this : https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/analyze-dotnet-project-dependencies-part-1/ but it's only the start of the journey to find all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that with the architecture features of visual studio. But it is a enterprise feature. You can also map external references (i have in mind from my last use).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/map-dependencies-across-your-solutions?view=vs-2017